# Parsing incoming TCP stream of Ascii chars, handle backspace char

Tags: f#, ascii, telnet

I need to parse input streams from a socket.
The data is sent from a Telnet client, and thus I want to process incoming strings by finding the first `'\r'` character in the stream, then pick the bytes before the return char and finally process any `backspace` `'\b'` chars.

What would be the idiomatic way to deal with the `'\b'` bits in here?
I'm currently using a mutable stack and push chars onto it, and if there is a backspace, I pop the last char.
Then just turn the result into a string.

But I figure there is probably some nice way to do this with pattern matching and tail recursion.
So, how can this be done the F# way?

```
let receiveInput (inputBuffer:StringBuilder) (received:Tcp.Received)=
    let text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received.Data.ToArray());
    inputBuffer.Append(text) |> ignore

    let all = inputBuffer.ToString()
    match all.IndexOf('\r') with
    | enter when enter >= 0 ->
        let textToProcess = all.Substring(0,enter)
        inputBuffer.Remove(0,enter+2) |> ignore

        //this is the part I'm wondering about
        let stack = new Stack<char>()
        for c in textToProcess do
            if c = '\b' then stack.Pop() |> ignore
            else stack.Push c

        let input = new System.String(stack |> Seq.rev |> Seq.toArray)

        Some(input)
    | _ ->
        None
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start by isolating the problematic part to a function:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let handleBackspaces textToProcess : string =
    let stack = Stack<char>()
    for c in textToProcess do
        if c = '\b' then stack.Pop() |> ignore
        else stack.Push c
    stack |> Seq.rev |> Seq.toArray |> String
```

This has a single mutable variable (`stack`). Whenever you have a mutating variable, you can replace it with an accumulator value in a recursive function. Here's one way to do it:

```
open System

let handleBackspaces' textToProcess : string =
    let rec imp acc = function
        | [] -> acc
        | '\b'::cs -> imp (acc |> List.tail) cs
        | c::cs -> imp (c::acc) cs
    textToProcess |> Seq.toList |> imp [] |> List.rev |> List.toArray |> String
```

You'll notice that I've called the accumulator value for `acc`. The `imp` function has the type `char list -> char list -> char list`, and it matches on the incoming `char list`: if it's empty, it returns the accumulator; if it has `'\b'` as the head, it removes the previous `char` from the accumulator by using `List.tail`; and in all other cases, it cons the first `char` to to accumulator and calls itself recursively.

Here's a (hopefully satisfactory) FSI session:

```
> handleBackspaces' "b\bfoo";;
val it : string = "foo"
> handleBackspaces' "foo";;
val it : string = "foo"
> handleBackspaces' "bar\bz";;
val it : string = "baz"
> handleBackspaces' "bar\b\boo";;
val it : string = "boo"
> handleBackspaces' "b\bfa\boo";;
val it : string = "foo"
```

Once one understands how to model something as a recursive function, it should be possible to implement it using a fold instead, as Ryan W Gough points out. Here's one way to do it:

```
let handleBackspaces'' textToProcess : string =
    textToProcess
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc c -> if c = '\b' then acc |> List.tail else c::acc) []
    |> List.rev
    |> List.toArray
    |> String
```

Comment: Ah yes, it should be fold not reduce, had not realised the difference in f#

Comment: @RyanWGough `reduce` is similar to `fold`, but it crashes when the input is empty.

Comment: Thanks, awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Feels like this could be done with a reduce? Cons the character to the accumulator if its not a backspace, if it is then just set the accumulator to its tail?

Comment: Should be a fold, not reduce, as mentioned in Mark Seemann's answer.